# Solr Cloud Replication Benefit

Tags: solr4, solrcloud

Can anyone tell me, whats the benefit of having more number of replicas of a shard other than fault torrance? Does having more replicas enable to distribute the load among available replicas and leader  thus improve query response time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. More replicas means load distribution as well as failover.
You divide data into shards when single server cannot cope with it, and you add new replicas when the existing server(s) cannot cope with QPS (queries per second) rate.